# Wiki/Lua: Where do I place modules?

Tags: lua, mediawiki, scribunto

I'm building a Wiki on my computer and I would like to use Template:Infobox person.
I have uploaded the template and also all dependencies it wants. Now it says the module "Check for unknown parameters" does not exist. I found the module on www.wikipedia.org and tried to export/import it but I still get the same error. Where should I place the module and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Scribunto module named "Check for unknown parameters" would go to `Module:Check_for_unknown_parameters`